# Указание url в javascript под yii

Tags: javascript, yii

Как в ajax-запросе указывать url к экшну контроллера? Пока оставил так:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?r=site/getAllObjects', 
});
```

Работает, но это как-то неизящно. Если раскомментировать url-manager, то, естественно, все перестает работать.

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убираем из пути index.php это давно пора сделать.

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false, // не показывать имя скрипта
            'caseSensitive'=>false,
```

+ .htaccess все скидываем на index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Отправляем запрос на сервер.

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/site/getallobjects",
```

А так написать сложно? в чем суть проблемы не могу понять?

Comment: @Shrek, несложно, когда направят в нужное русло) Сам я только начинающий веб-разработчик. Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 2):

В `<head>` обьявляете глобальную переменную:

```
var js_url = '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/needAction'); ?>';
```

Потом в любом js скрипте обращатесь к ней. В Вашем случае будет так:

```
$.ajax({
   url: js_url, 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('/site/details') ?>",
    .....
```

Comment: @sash, нужно перенастраивать сервер, который не ищет php код в файлах js. Ладно, это решаемо. Из этого файла не "видно" класс Yii и фреймворк в целом. Что для меня не решаемо(( Подключение просто файла /framework/yii.php не помогло. Нужно "создавать приложение" (CreateApplication) со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: можно и по другому.

Comment: @sash, как, если не секрет?

Comment: не секрет, у Вас горит или обождеть чуток ?

Comment: @sash, не горит совершенно) впринципе вообще работать может и способом из вопроса, но интерес спортивный не удовлетворен.

Comment: сейчас, я свою хренотей доделаю, или придумаю, как сделать и помогу...